# Titan - Cassandra - Elasticsearch :: Connection refused

Tags: java, titan

I am running Titan 0.5.0 with Cassandra 2.0.8.

When I first ran my Java client with a local Titan-Cassandra I could connect to it. Now that I deployed the Titan-Cassandra remotely on a Debian Wheezy with dedicated user I have a "Connection refused exception" (see stack below). I can connect to Titan via Rexter on the remote server via http://my-domain.com:8182 and I can see my vertices and edges.

*What is the changes to do on a local configuration (Java client and Titan on same machine) to make Titan with Cassandra and Elasticsearch run on a remote machine accessed by my Java client?*

Java client code

```
private final URL titanConfiguration =TitanRepository.class.getResource("/conf/titan-cassandra.properties");
public TitanGraph load() {
    return TitanFactory.open(titanConfiguration.getPath());
}
```

**Working configuration with local Titan-Cassandra:**

Java configuration titan-cassandra.properties

```
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5

index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=127.0.0.1
index.search.client-only=true

schema.default=none
```

No change in the Titan conf directory

**NOT working java configuration with Titan-Cassandra on remote server**

Java configuration titan-cassandra.properties

```
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
storage.hostname=192.168.1.20   <<< OR http://my-domain.com
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5

index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=192.168.1.20    <<< OR http://my-domain.com
index.search.client-only=true

schema.default=none
```

changes in Titan conf directory

- rexster-cassandra-es.xml:

> `<base-uri>http://my-domain.com</base-uri>`
>   `<index.search.hostname>192.168.1.20</index.search.hostname>`

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager

    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:425)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:366)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1208)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:92)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:60)
    at be.jiliant.spotmydate.server.TitanRepository.load(TitanRepository.java:30)
    at be.jiliant.spotmydate.server.persist.processor.PersistProcessor.process(PersistProcessor.java:38)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:103)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:685)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:623)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:591)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:246)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1031)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:218)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.<init>(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:196)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeRawConnection(CTConnectionFactory.java:87)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:52)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:21)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:215)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: actually I don't understand very well how Titan, Rexter, Cassandra and Elasticsearch are started and run together. Is there any good tutorial I could follow to understand those concepts? Or should I start and configure all those components separately?

Answer (score 0):

If Rexster runs on the same (remote) box and can connect, but you can't connect from your local machine, then it's most likely a Cassandra configuration issue. In `cassandra.yaml` set `rpc_address` to `0.0.0.0` (currently you've probably set it to `127.0.0.1`), restart Cassandra and try to connect again.

Comment: it did not help. I tried in combination of both localhost or ip of box in listen_address

Comment: Can you share your cassandra.yaml in a Gist? I bet any of the IP-related settings is wrong (could also be ```listen_address```, ```broadcast_address``` or ```seeds```; the latter is unlikely when Cassandra starts without errors).

Comment: both my cassandra.yaml and rexter-cassandra-es.xml are available at [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3ae49ddd9668ef79f76b). In the rexter-cassandra-es.xml I change 2 parameters base-uri and storage.hostname

Comment: ```listen_address``` is ```localhost```, I don't think this can work. Try to use the public or private IP of your host (```192.168.1.20```?) for the ```listen_address``` as well as for the ```seeds```.

Comment: I already tried the public ip of my host in the listen_address. I didn't try to change the seeds but it could be the issue. I saw failure around ring at the client side. I'll try to change this ASAP and keep you posted. Thx

Comment: thank you, I think it worked but I cannot prove because now I have an issue with elastic search (in short Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex ...Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available).
I don't know if I use the correct approach. I thought that using Titan with the rexter-cassandra-es configuration would be easy. Wouldn't it be easier to run them all separately? I am in trial and error mode and I don't find all the information on how to handle this

Comment: Actually I always run them all separately. Whatever works best for you.